# How to find if I have the same domain name but using a with different extension

Tags: php

I have a problem that I was thinking it was going to be simple to solve but I cannot figure it out.

I have a database full of URLs like:

- http://www.domain.com/page.html
- http://domain.com/page.html
- http://sub.domain.co.in/page.html
- http://sub.sub.domain.it/page.html
- http://other.domain.net/page.html
- http://ok.domain.com/ok.html
- etc...

now, given `http://www.domain.co.uk/page.html`

I need to figure out if such page it is already in the database assuming that the different extension does not change the content.

The final goal is simple, I am building a site where people can submit pages, those pages needs to be unique to avoid duplication of content.  Users are submitting google maps .com and google maps .co.in creating a duplication of the same page, what I need  to do is to figure out if the page submitted is already been submitted with a different domain extension.  I will also do a check on title and content if found, just in case the domain extension DOES change the content ( like www.wyska.net and www.wyska.com )

in other words:

- maps.google.com === maps.google.it === maps.google.co.in === maps.google.co.uk .....

only if content is "similar" (I will have to work on figure out what "similar" means too)

so far I have (but it doesn't work):

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.domain.com/text.html';  //works with this domain
$parse = parse_url($url);
var_dump($parse);
var_dump(pathinfo($parse['host']));

$url = 'http://sub.sub.domain.co.in/text.html';  //does not work with this domain
$parse = parse_url($url);
var_dump($parse);
var_dump(pathinfo($parse['host']));
?>
```

if necessary I can even break the domain in different parts and store those parts instead than the full domain.

I as thinking to do a search replace on the domain extension, but I haven't been able to find a full list of domain extension to use.  Something like: if it ends with any of those strings, then remove that part from the domain

Comment: The subdomain/TLD being different means the pages are different. They *may* be aliases of each other, but this is by no means guaranteed!

Comment: Similarly you could run into the same content with default documents, so example.com/index.php vs. example.co.uk/

Comment: Yes, I know that different subdomains means different content, the subdomain needs to be unique, the extension is the one that worries me, like I said an example is the `maps.google.*` or `www.amazon.*`.  The content will be a big part of this check.  the `example.com` and example.co.uk` is a perfect example where I will have to check the content as well to make sure that they are different sites and not the same with different extensions.